# Google Chrome extension: Use Javascript inside webkit notifications?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, notifications, google-chrome-extension

I have been following the [Google Chrome Extensions Developer's guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html) and have been able so far to create an extension with a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) without popup that would trigger a webkit notification in HTML format.

Fact is that this HTML file contains action buttons, links and javascript, but none of them seems to respond.

Is this a by-design behavior or is there a way for embedding javascript/links/buttons in these webkit notifications?

**EDIT:**

Here are some new insights on the subject:

#### Javascript

Here is an HTML notification page that doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  alert("hey");
</script>
</head>
<body>
  content
</body>
</html>
```

As a result, the notification is all blank ; the text *"content"* isn't displayed.

But if I remove the "alert", the text *"content"* is displayed.

I first thought that Javascript was blocking the page from rendering correctly, but I tried something else:

```
<script>document.write("content");</script>
```

This javascript command is correctly executed and displays the text *"content"*. We can then assume that Javascript is enabled even in the webkit desktop notifications, but the *"alert"* function is disabled, and breaks the rendering of the notification page.

#### Links

Some links work, some don't. Here is a quick list of those I've tested so far:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link</a>                   # => Doesn't work
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_top">Link</a>     # => Doesn't work
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_parent">Link</a>  # => Doesn't work
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>   # => Works (new tab)
```

Comment: Some sample code might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all explained in the [Chromium Desktop Notifications API Specification](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) where it's clearly said that:

> If a user agent implements createHTMLNotification, it should show HTML notifications as independent browsing contexts which are equivalent in functionality to any other HTML web page, except with the following properties:
>
> - **The notification cannot be navigated**.  The Location attribute of the window object in the notification context should be readonly.  All links should open in new, non-notification browsing contexts.
> - If close() is invoked on the window object in the notification context in response to a user gesture, the user agent should proceed as if the user closed the notification, including all required event processing.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: `createHTMLNotification()` has been [removed from the draft spec and also from Chrome](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/8vWo8hq4pDm), so this will no longer work.

The closest thing is an `onclick` handler on the whole notification window.  It's less discoverable (doesn't look like a link), and I haven't tested if it's possible to navigate to a link from it.